# css positioning not allowing to put on right side

Tags: css

This css code is not allowing me to put next item to be right side, I have tried but next item that is picture always remain under popular class.

```
#content .wrapcontent .popular{  
width: 250px;
margin: 00px 0px 10px 0;
color: rgba(148, 145, 145, 0.84);   
background:#FFFFFF;
}
#content .wrapcontent .popular .footer-nav{         
color: rgba(148, 145, 145, 0.84);
margin: 00px 0px 00px 10px; 
}
#content .wrapcontent .popular .footer-nav a{    
color: rgba(148, 145, 145, 0.84);   
}
```

I want to put next thing on its right side.

Comment: Where's the markup? I'd also recommend making this in http://jsfiddle.net/ so others can see what you're talking about.

Comment: Use float or inline-block

Comment: Because stackoverflow is not meant to be a forum or question board. When asking a question, you need to be very clear what you want and at least showed some effort to fix it by yourself by research.

Comment: put your html in there and create a jsfiddle. I'm positive people won't down vote then.

Comment: -1 for you absolutely ignorant way to edit your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If css code is not allowing you to put next item to be right side, You must try float command to for that adjustment or to put items on left or right.

```
float:left;
```

or

```
float:right;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a float left and the n the following div will appear on the right side of the first div

```
.firstDiv{
float:left;
}
```

Comment: thanks bro 
well i need you a bit more help
i have uploaded files here http://gangstersonline.comuf.com/villa2/
if you will check still there is some gap under the pictures on the right side of "Popular Destination"
i did use float:left; to put picture on the right side of "Popular Destination", but now how i can cover that gap which is under these pictures ?
should i show you complete css file ?

Comment: Either you have margins on your divs or because the divs divs are in rows, the tow height takes the height of the largest div therefore making a gap between the rest of the divs